# SQL pivot/unpivot

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query, but I want to add an extra column which would show the `Month1Data` and `Month2Data` fields. How do I add this to the query?

```
WITH pivot_cte 
     AS (SELECT performancedata.[year], 
                performance.referenceno, 
                performance.shortname, 
                performancedata.month4base, 
                performancedata.month4data, 
                performancedata.month5data, 
                performancedata.month5base, 
                performancedata.month6data, 
                performancedata.month6base, 
                performancedata.month7data, 
                performancedata.month7base, 
                performancedata.month8data, 
                performancedata.month8base, 
                performancedata.month9data, 
                performancedata.month9base, 
                performancedata.month10data, 
                performancedata.month10base, 
                performancedata.month11data, 
                performancedata.month11base, 
                performancedata.month12data, 
                performancedata.month12base, 
                performancedata.month1base, 
                performancedata.month1data, 
                performancedata.month2base, 
                performancedata.month2data, 
                performancedata.month3data, 
                performancedata.month3base, 
                performancedata.defaulttarget, 
                performancedata.texttarget, 
                performance.deleted, 
                performance.active 
         FROM   performancedata 
                INNER JOIN performance 
                        ON performancedata.performanceid = 
                           performance.performanceid 
         WHERE  ( performancedata.year = 2015 
                  AND performance.referenceno = 21 )) 
SELECT [year], 
       referenceno, 
       shortname, 
       active, 
       deleted, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) [Month], 
       valuebase 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   pivot_cte)p 
       UNPIVOT (valuebase 
               FOR [Values] IN (month4base, 
                                month5base, 
                                month6base, 
                                month7base, 
                                month8base, 
                                month9base, 
                                month10base, 
                                month11base, 
                                month12base, 
                                month1base, 
                                month2base, 
                                month3base)) AS unpivot_dt;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add your  code using code sample option when you ask a question and better if you provide sample data

Comment: Cleaned up the question and title